# How do I link autocomplete on a textbox to a database table? C# 2.0

Tags: c#, data-binding, textbox, autocomplete

I'm using Visual Studio 2005, C# with Framework 2.0.  I'd like to use auto complete, but would like the list to come from a table in my database.

Is there a way to databind the AutoCompleteSoure?

Comment: You really should specify WinForms, WPF, WebForms, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this [blogpost](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/01/winforms-autocomplete-textbox-using-c.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want to do by using the AjaxControlToolkit AutoComplete

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with auto-complete in WinForms in C#. Here is the example:

1. Change the `AutoCompleteMode` of textbox to `SuggestAppend`.
2. Change the `AutoCompleteSource` to `CustomSource`.

Now, write the following code in Enter_Event of textbox to load data from any table:

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection acs = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
acs.Clear();

try
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    OleDbCommand odc = new OleDbCommand("<your sql statement>", <your connection>);
    OleDbDataReader odr = odc.ExecuteReader();

    while (odr.Read())
    {
        acs.Add(odr["name"].ToString());
    }

    textbox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = acs;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new ex;
}
finally
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```

Hope this code helps. Please reply for any other queries.